# How many different ways are there to create a wall with bricks?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

How many different ways are there to create a wall that length is n and height is 2 with bricks ? 
Our bricks sizes are 2x1 and 1x1. And bricks are two-dimensional.

```
For example;
if n=1, we need one 2x1 or we need two 1x1 bricks    
        so result is 2 different way

if n=2, we need two 2x1 (vertical and horizontal) 
        or we need four 1x1 bricks                    
        so result is 7 different way

if n=3, result is 20 (Unfortunately I'm not sure :/)
```

... etc.

I need an algorithm according to this results, but I didn't associate this results with each other. 
Can you help me please ?

Comment: For n=2, there are 7 different ways. Two 2x2 vertical, but left or right brick can be replaced by two 1x1. Two 2x2 horizontal, but top or bottom brick can be replaced by two 1x1.  And four 1x1.

Comment: you are right. And i guess if n=3 , result is 20  but still i couldn't do any relation between them o.O

Comment: Is this Project Euler?

Comment: I don't know whether Project Euler but it's one of the question of my Algorithm homework and that is all I can do for now. If you have an idea I want to know and learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say a wall has two levels of N "slots".

P[L1][L2] = the number of possibilities to put bricks so that the first L1 slots on the first level and the first L2 slots on the second level are filled with brick material.

For example, this configuration is captured in P[3][4] (bricks have numbers: 11, 22, 3, 44):

```
(1st level =>) 1122
(2nd level =>) 344
```

Case 1: L1 = L2

```
....
....
```

You put one 2x1 brick vertically at the end => You add P[L1-1][L2-1] to P[L1][L2]

```
...1
...1
```

You put one 1x1 brick on level 1 at the end => You add P[L1-1][L2] to P[L1][L2]

```
....
...1
```

You put one 1x1 brick on level 2 at the end => You add P[L1][L2-1] to P[L1][L2]

```
...1
....
```

You put two 2x1 bricks horizontally, one on level 1, one on level 2 => You add P[L1-2][L2-2] to P[L1][L2]

```
..22
..11
```

Now we're done with the case when it ends on a vertical line. From this we observe the solution of your problem is in P[N][N]. But we are left with the cases when the bricks don't add up to the same length on the two levels.

Case 2: L1-1 = L2, something like

```
...
....
```

You put one 1x1 brick on level 1 => Add P[L1-1][L2] to P[L1][L2]

```
...
...1
```

You put one 2x1 brick horizontally on level 1 => Add P[L1-2][L2] to P[L1][L2]

```
...
..11
```

Case 3: L1+1 = L2, simply symmetrical.

The idea here is that cases should not overlap, i.e., one brick configuration should not be counted multiple times. Now we are done with the general case. All you have left is to handle the initial cases.

Case nothing-nothing: P[0][0] = 1 (you can have only one zero-length wall).

```
Nothing
Nothing
```

Case nothing-1: P[0](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static) = 1 (you can only add a 1x1 brick on level 2).

```
.
Nothing
```

Case 1-nothing: P[1](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static)[0] = 1 (you can only add a 1x1 brick on level 1).

```
Nothing
.
```

Do this on paper and make sure all indexes are right.

Also sit down and understanding this [TopCoder tutorial on dynamic programming](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static). It will get you far one day.